# All principal minors are equal to zero

Tags: matrices

Let's assume that all principal minors of symetric square matrix $A$ ($n\times n$) are equal to zero, then what definiteness does this matrix have? It's obvious that it's semidefinite, of course. But which exactly semidefiniteness is it? Negative, positive, or maybe something like "neutral"???!

Comment: Please show some of your thoughts on the question.

Comment: Are all principal minors zero, or are only all *leading* principal minors zero? The answers are different.

Comment: @Vishal I have no idea. All my thoughts were said in the questions...

Comment: @user1551 Yes, all principal minors. In symetric matrix all principal minors are equal, hence we can use only all leading principal minors for the definiteness investigation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** If all principal minors are zero, show that the matrix is zero and hence it is *both* positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite.

If only  the leading principal minors are guaranteed to be zero, the matrix **can** be positive semidefinite, negative semidefinite (it is easy to construct a diagonal matrix example) or indefinite (for the matrix to be indefinite, it is at least $3\times 3$).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought that ¨both¨ variant is immposible, but now I know that it an be.